# Appium java giving null as output

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to open a calculator app in android using appium.
But I am getting this error,
This is the function:

```
    
    public static void openCalculator() throws Exception{
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Redmi Note 7S");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "39aded9");
        cap.setCapability("platformname", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10 QKQ1.190910.002");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.miui.calculator12.3.16");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity");
        
        
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);  
        
        System.out.println("Application Started....");
        
    }
```

I am getting this error, followed a youtube video, but still getting this.

```
null
no protocol: 127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at appiumtests.calculatorTest.openCalculator(calculatorTest.java:46)
    at appiumtests.calculatorTest.main(calculatorTest.java:23)
```

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub`?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 102 milliseconds

Comment: This issue is comming

Comment: This is quite obvious, you are supplying `platformname` instead of `platformName` capability key :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
 at appiumtests.Calculator.openCalculator(Calculator.java:49)
 at appiumtests.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: This issue is coming

Comment: This seems no longer relevant to the initial question and code, you should probably open a new one or at least update the question with more code and latest exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
 at appiumtests.Calculator.openCalculator(Calculator.java:49)
 at appiumtests.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 2 more

Comment: The code is same as upper but when i run the code . this error is coming and also not connect with appium

Comment: Looks like you are probably working with Appium java-client that is version 8.x.x, if you move back to version 7.x.x it will resolve this error I guess. Alternatively you can look for migration guides for the newer version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249181/discussion-between-sachin-soni-and-drunkencheetah).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concluding @drunkencheetah and @Sachin Soni discussion above,

## Short description of the converstion:

### The calculator app package was not being detected so @drunkencheetah suggested changing it to chrome as it was easy and no extra installation was required.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Galaxy M21");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "RZ8N224NG1L");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "12");
        cap.setCapability("waitForAppLaunch", "false");
        cap.setCapability("uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout", "60000");
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        
        
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        
        
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");  
        
        driver = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(url, cap);
        
        System.out.println("Application Started....");
```

as @drunkencheetah suggested:

> cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.chrome.Main");
>
> or

> cap.setCapability("appActivity",
> "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");    might work

@Sachin Soni tried `cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.chrome.Main");`

but it gave error.

### Eventually `cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");` worked!

#### Extra

To do this with another app try installing `Apk Analyzer` which will help in displaying `appPackage` and `appActivity` for an App.